# adding a private key of another user

Tags: linux, ssh, macos

I am running on macos as usera. I want to ssh from usera@cli, but with a key that I have of user b. e.g

`usera@mbp ssh userb@server`

The main point is adding this rsa keychain to my personal computer and logging as userb without having to log into the server

What should I do for this?
I have the id_rsa private key of userb in plaintext

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to login in host `server` with account `userb` using this other key you can use command:

```
ssh -i /path/to/_key_of_userb userb@server
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to run as userb from my own personal machine

Comment: @Stat.Enthus, please clarify in the question. At the moment it's hard to get what you want. BTW you can login as userb using above command on the same computer (if this is you want)